# Getting an image to show after and if/else statement jQuery

Tags: jquery

The last if/else statement in the below code is working. I put in a sample string to see if it would show that rather than a particular image. Why does the statement apparently work, without showing the image?

Here is my snippet:

```js
var model = {
 boardSize: 7,
 numShips: 3,
 shipLength: 3,
 shipsSunk: 0,
 
 ships: [
  {locations: ["A6", "B6","C6"]},
  {locations:["C4", "D4", "E4"]},
  {locations:["B0", "B1", "B2"]}
 ]
};

$(document).on("ready", function(){
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
    mouse.x = e.clientX && e.pageX; 
    mouse.y = e.clientY && e.pageY;
}, false);

var currentXPosition;
var currentYPosition;

$('td').on('mouseenter', function(){
    currentXPosition = $(this).data('x');
    currentYPosition = $(this).data('y');
});

$('.torpedos').on('mousedown', 'img', function(e){
    var node = $(this);
    var position = node.offset();
    
    var handlers = {
        mousemove : function(e){
            node.css({
                left : mouse.x, 
                top :  mouse.y
            });
        },
        mouseup : function(e){
            $(this).off(handlers);
            $('img').fadeOut('slow').remove();
            $('<img src="Torpedo.png">').appendTo('.torpedos');
            $('.torpedos').find("img").hide().fadeIn('slow');
                        
            var status;
            var currentPosition = currentXPosition + currentYPosition;
            for(var i = 0; i < model.ships.length; i++){
            var ship = model.ships[i];
                if(status === 'hit'){
                break
                }
            for(var j = 0; j < ship.locations.length; j++){
                if(ship.locations[j] === currentPosition){
                    status = 'hit';
                    break
                }else{
                    status = 'miss';
                }
            } 
        }
            var position = $("[data-x= '" + currentXPosition + " '][data-y= '" + currentYPosition + " ']");
            if(status === 'hit'){
                $(position).append("Hello");
            }else{
                $(position).append("GoodBye");
            }
        }
    };
    $(document).on(handlers);
});

});
```

```css
body {
 background-color:black;
}
div#board {
 position: relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:863px;
 margin:auto;
 background: url("board.jpg") no-repeat;
}
div#messageArea {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 color: rgb(83, 175, 19);
}
.fire {
 background: url("ship.png") no-repeat center center;
}
.missFire {
 background: url("miss.png") no-repeat center center;
}
table{
 border-spacing: 0px; 
 position: absolute;
 left: 173px;
 top: 98px;
}
td{
 width:94px;
 height:94px;
}
img{
 width:94px;
 height:94px;
 position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang = "en">
  <head>
   <meta charset = "utf-8">
   <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <title>Battleship!!!!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="board">
   <div id="messageArea"></div>

   <table>
    <tr>
     <td data-x="A" data-y="0"></td><td data-x="A" data-y="1"></td><td data-x="A" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="A" data-y="3"></td>
     <td data-x="A" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="A" data-y+"5"></td> <td data-x="A" data-y="6">
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td data-x="B" data-y="0"></td> <td data-x="B" data-y="1"></td> <td data-x="B" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="B" data-y="3"></td>
     <td data-x="B" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="B" data-y="5"></td> <td data-x="B" data-y="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td data-x="C" data-y="0"></td> <td data-x="C" data-y="1"></td> <td data-x="C" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="C" data-y="3"></td>
    <td data-x="C" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="C" data-y="5"></td> <td data-x="C" data-y="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td data-x="D" data-y="0"></td> <td data-x="D" data-y="1"></td> <td data-x="D" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="D" data-y="3"></td>
    <td data-x="D" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="D" data-y="5"></td> <td data-x="D" data-y="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td data-x="E" data-y="0"></td> <td data-x="E" data-y="1"></td> <td data-x="E" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="E" data-y="3"></td>
    <td data-x="E" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="E" data-y="5"></td> <td data-x="E"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td data-x="F" data-y="0"></td> <td data-x="F" data-y="1"></td> <td data-x="F" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="F" data-y="3"></td>
    <td data-x="F" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="F" data-y="5"></td> <td data-x="F" data-y="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td data-x="G" data-y="0"></td> <td data-x="G" data-y="1"></td> <td data-x="G" data-y="2"></td> <td data-x="G" data-y="3"></td>
    <td data-x="G" data-y="4"></td> <td data-x="G" data-y="5"></td> <td data-x="G" data-y="6"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
    <div class="torpedos">
    <img src="Torpedo.png">
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="updatedbattle.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind event handlers inside other handlers. Every time the `mousedown` event happens, it will add another `mousemove` and `mouseup` handler. Then when these events occur, it will run the handler multiple times.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable?

Comment: I was limited to the plugins I can use. This was the best way to go about it without draggable and droppable.

Comment: It's impossible to tell the difference between `.fire` and `.missFire`, since they both use nonexistent images as their background.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `console.log(status);` put:

```
$('.fire').toggle(status == 'hit');
$('.missFire').toggle(status == 'miss');
```

If the argument to `.toggle()` is `true`, the element is shown, otherwise it's hidden.

Comment: For some reason it will not show. i have been trying to put another if/ else statement. Each space in the grid has a data attribute. data-x = to a letter and data-y = to a number. For example, the first td on the grid would be equal to  data-x= A and data-y = 0.

Comment: if(status === 'hit'){
                $("[data-x= '" + currentXPosition + " '][data-y= '" + currentYPosition + " ']").css("fire");
            }else{
                $("[data-x= '" + currentXPosition + " '][data-y= '" + currentYPosition + " ']").css("missFire");
            }

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or stack snippet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634009/getting-an-image-to-show-after-and-if-else-statement-jquery-continued

Comment: I've tried running your snippet. I'm able to drag the box, but I don't see anything to drop it on.